# Using / To Search Using ZSH

Tags: vim, zsh

I like to search my command history using the following keybindings:

```
<ESC>/
Type in command fragment<RET>
n => to look backwards in time
N => to go forwards
```

This works well when you are using 'vi mode' in ZSH, but I recently added vim as my default editor in my .zshenv file. Now when I press "/", I see this:

```
tom@flanders ~ZSH [master]
± %                          
zsh: do you wish to see all 5226 possibilities (5226 lines)?
```

I found this keybinding that looked promising, but it didn't make a difference:

```
bindkey -M vicmd '/' history-incremental-pattern-search-backward
```

Is there something else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I do find this a bit odd: by default, zsh uses emacs-style (escape followed by a key) key combos, unless it is in vi-mode, at which point emacs-style key combos are disabled. zsh also puts itself in vi mode if you use a vi-like editor as your default editor. So, it would seem to me that you were probably *not* originally in vi mode, until you edited your zshenv.

So, I would first ask: are you 100% sure you have always been using vi mode? That is to say, does `bindkey -e` solve your issue (try it in an open shell)?

It may be that you really would be better off in emacs mode (`bindkey -e`). On the other hand, it may be that you'd like to be in vi mode, but would be [better off with some emacs style bindings](http://paulgoscicki.com/archives/2012/09/zsh-vi-mode-with-emacs-keybindings/).

Or, maybe I'm wrong completely, and I should just focus on your bind statement, which is incorrectly written.

First of all, the inclusion of the "vicmd" bit prevents this from working in insert (normal) mode: it only works if you *first* press escape (by itself) to leave insert mode for command mode (as you would do in vim). So, you can't press "esc-/" as a chord (try pressing escape, releasing it, then pressing "/").

Try the following binding:

```
bindkey '\e/' history-incremental-pattern-search-backward
```

Now you should be able to press "escape-/" as a chord and get the desired results.